# Humans conquering space through matter manipulation

Tags: story-identification

The story centered around the friendship between two humans as they mastered space travel through matter and/or time-space manipulation. As they come into contact with alien species, they eventually come across a hostile one which proceeds to force the humans to demonstrate ultimate superiority through the creation of "fixed" space in the path of the alien's homeworld orbit - the result of which is catastrophic as the planet's momentum essentially flattens it against this immoveable disc.

I happened across it in a larger volume of Golden Age stories (including The Survivors by Godwin) .. the title of which is lost to me thanks to my Nook v1 giving up the ghost.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

That sounds a great deal like John W. Campbell's *Invaders from the Infinite* series.  Mastery of Space-Time - check. Nasty aliens - check. Stopping planet in tracks with immovable disk - check.

The super-scientists were Arcot, Wade and Morey and that's frequently the name of the series, which was eventually published in three volumes as *The Black Star Passes*, *The Islands of Space* and *Invaders from the Infinite*.

The stories were first published in the early 30s and marked Campbell as the leader in Super-Science stories.  The stories were published first as a couple of novellas followed by two novels.  See ISFDB: https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?827 for details.  (I have not read the original publications, but read the books published in the 1950s, which may well have been edited.)

The "fixed space" you speak of was "artificial matter" in the stories.  The gimmick was that Arcot, Wade and Morey had discovered a way to create artificial matter which could only exist where it was created and, consequently was effectively infinitely hard -- at least as long as the gadget doing the creating had enough power. So one Bad Guys planet was destroyed as described in the question using a giant cup of artificial matter in the planet's -- Thett, I believe -- orbit.

Along the way, A,W&M discover how to manipulate time to achieve FTL travel *and* separately how to manipulate space to do likewise.  Then they combine the two to get even faster travel.  They invent several all-new materials made of hardened light and hardened cosmic rays, a molecular ray projector which turns the random motion of heat into directed motion, and some sort of ESP-based controlling system.  (Not bad for a couple years' work!)

This really is the ultimate in Super-Science!

Comment: All available from [here](https://www.gutenberg.org/ebooks/author/9112)

Comment: Wow, and I thought Larry Niven invented crazy stuff.

Comment: I wish I could describe the flood of memories released as you described the stories ... I wish you all the good will this universe has available. Thank you!